# calling Axios get API request in Formik

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios, formik

Earlier I was not using `Formik` so I was calling API using parameter like below. All the parameters are optional.

```js
const submit = async (e: SyntheticEvent) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const param = {
    ...(certificateNo && { certificateNo: certificateNo }),
    ...(protoColNo && { protoColNo: protoColNo }),
    ...(requestStatus && { requestStatus: requestStatus }),
    ...(sponser && { sponser: sponser }),
    ...(country && { country: country }),
    ...(noOfSubjects && { noOfSubjects: noOfSubjects }),
    ...(startDate && { startDate: startDate }),
    ...(endDate && { endDate: endDate }),
  };
  console.log(param);
  const { data } = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/certificates', {
    params: param,
  });
  console.log(data);
  setFlag(true);
  setResponse(data);
};
```

using `Formik`

```js
const handleSubmit = async (values: any) => {
  const { data } = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/certificates', {
    params: { values }, //values contains all the parameter value.
  });
  console.log(data);
  setResponse(data.data);
  alert(JSON.stringify(data));
};
```

But now I am using `Formik`. I dont know how to make this `value` optional. it contains all the above `parameter` but since we dont use hooks here I am not sure how to fetch individual elements from values. if I am doing `value.certificateNo` it is giving error.

Comment: By using the short form syntax here `params: { values }` you are creating an object `params.values.certificateNo` which I assume from your previous code that the server will not handle this correctly

Comment: `values` are input values which are wrapped inside formik component or formik hook you defined. If you try to use the value which is not part of it you need to fetch directly

Comment: its inside formik component Shubham

Answer (score 0):

It worked like below.

```
 const handleSubmit =async (values:any)=>{
```

//check the below line

```
        const { certificateNo, protoColNo, requestStatus, researchTitle, sponser,country,noOfSubjects,startDate,endDate} = values;
        const param = {
            ...(certificateNo && { certificateNo: certificateNo }),
            ...(protoColNo && { protoColNo: protoColNo }),
            ...(requestStatus && { requestStatus: requestStatus }),
            ...(researchTitle && {researchTitle: researchTitle}),
            ...(sponser && { sponser: sponser }),
            ...(country && { country: country }),
            ...(noOfSubjects && { noOfSubjects: noOfSubjects }),
            ...(startDate && { startDate: startDate }),
            ...(endDate && { endDate: endDate }),
        };

            const { data } = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/certificates',{
                params: param,
            });
            console.log(data)
            setResponse(data.data);
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
          }
```